# Removing encoding in a string

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a very strange issue - I have included a text file to extract variables from, and this happens:

```
var_dump($kw);
returns:
string(19) "fut coins"

echo "keyword $kw";
returns:
keyword: 0f0i0f0a0 0c0o0i0n0s0
```

Is there anyway to remove this encoding of the 0's from the string?

Comment: This looks really strange, can you please show us a hexdump of this string? (See: bin2hex)

Comment: the bin2hex shows:

00630061007200720065006c006100670065002000730061006c006c00650020006400650020006200610069006e00

Comment: This looks like UTF-16 but then it would be the string "carrelage salle de bain" and i dont understand why it ends with "00" since thats just a "half" of a char.

Comment: Oh, i think the last 00 belongs to the closing " or '. Convert the input-file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 then it should work.

Comment: Which function can I use to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example (assuming you just need to get rid of zeroes)
By your encoding example above, an actual `0` char will appear as two consecutive zeroes, so first encode it to some special string, then decode after removing all the unnecessary zeroes.

```
$kw = str_replace('00', ';;;zero;;;', $kw);
$kw = str_replace('0', '', $kw);
$kw = str_replace(';;;zero;;;', '0', $kw);
```

This should work.  However, this is kind of a quick-and-dirty fix for your problem.

The fact that your string is arriving in your program with each character padded with zeroes is odd, and fixing that problem at its source would be the ideal solution.

Comment: How can I go around this if there is a 0 in the string? What is the core issue of this?

Comment: OK I've edited my answer a bit, it should now consider for the possibility that your string has authentic `0` chars in it